# Sql - How to count different column values grouped by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following problem - I have a table  with 4 columns: Id, Name, InsertTime, UpdateTime.
I want to count for each Name (NOT unique!) how many with the same name have **different** InsertTime or UpdateTime.
For example, if I have the following data:

```
ID NAME  INSERTED_TIME  UPDATE_TIME
1  maya  21-12-2015     21-12-2015
2  tal   22-12-2015     21-12-2015
3  maya  21-09-2015     21-12-2015
4  mark  21-12-2015     21-12-2015
5  mark  21-12-2015     21-12-2015
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
NAME  COUNT
maya  1
tal   0
mark  0
```

Explantion: "maya" has 1 duplicate with different InsertTime or UpdateTime. "tal" has no duplicates. And "mark" has a duplicate but both the InsertTime and UpdateTime are the same so it doesn't count.

I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 on t1.NAME=t2.NAME
where (t1.INSERTED_TIME<>t2.INSERTED_TIME or t1.UPDATE_TIME<>t2.UPDATE_TIME)
```

But this returns duplicates.
I also tried different approaches with GROUP BY - nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and count the rows for each name:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT NAME
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY NAME, INSERTED_TIME, UPDATE_TIME
)
SELECT NAME, count(*) - 1 COUNT
FROM CTE
GROUP BY NAME
```

Result:

```
NAME    COUNT
mark    0
maya    1
tal     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT NAME,
         RN = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY INSERTED_TIME,UPDATE_TIME) - 1
  FROM #table t1
)
SELECT NAME, [COUNT] = MAX(RN)
FROM cte
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406895)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT` to get the number of different values for `INSERTED_TIME` and `UPDATE_TIME` for each name, then simply deduct 1 from this number to get the output you require.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), INSERTED_TIME DATE, UPDATE_TIME DATE);
INSERT @T 
VALUES
    (1, 'maya', '2015-12-21', '2015-12-21'),
    (2, 'tal', '2015-12-22', '2015-12-21'),
    (3, 'maya', '2015-09-21', '2015-12-21'),
    (4, 'mark', '2015-12-21', '2015-12-21'),
    (5, 'mark', '2015-12-21', '2015-12-21');

SELECT  name, 
        [COUNT] = COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(INSERTED_TIME, UPDATE_TIME)) - 1
FROM    @T
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC;
```